# Is this Java polymorphism assignment ready for turn in?

Tags: java, arrays, polymorphism

### Problem:  Develop the ‘Shape’ application such that:

Implement an array of objects of various types (all five classes), in any order. In some type of a looping structure, demonstrate polymorphism by calling all three of the methods, draw, move, and erase.  That is, within the curly braces, there will be only three method calls.  Verify that the output messages come from all three methods, from all seven classes.
The only class that you should have to develop for this class will be the test application.  The seven classes from last week should remain unchanged.

Is the test class necessary? I couldn't get any output that way.
I am also getting 2 default constructors at the beginning of the run.
Should I use a super class for any of these? Any other tips are appreciated.

```
 public class Shapes{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    
        Shapes [ ] Array = {
             new Triangle ( " ", " ", " "),
             new Rectangle ( " ", " ", " "),
             new Square ( " ", " ", " "), 
             new Ellipse ( " ", " ", " "),
             new Circle ( " ", " ", " ")};
        
        
    //public void TestShapes (Shapes[] Array ) {
     for(int x =0; x<Array.length;x++)//iterates through array
       {
             System.out.println(x);
             System.out.println(Array[x].toString());
             
       }

        }
     }
    public class Triangle extends Shapes    {
    
    private String draw;
    private String erase;
    private String move;
    
    public String draw () {return draw; }
    public void draw (String d) {d = d ; }
    public String erase () {return erase; }
    public void erase (String e) { e = e ; }
    public String move () { return move; }
    public void move (String m) { m = m; }
    
    public Triangle ( ) {
            
        draw = " ";
        erase = " ";
        move = " ";
        System.out.println( "Default constructor " );
        
    }
    
    public Triangle (String d, String e, String m ) {
            
        draw = " Triangle - draw method \n";
        erase = " Triangle - erase method \n";
        move = " Triangle -  move method \n";
       // System.out.println( draw + erase + move);
        
    }
    public String toString()
   {
   String s = "";
   s+= /*" Triangle draw " + */ this.draw;
   s+= /*" Triangle erase " + */ this.erase;
   s+= /*" Triangle move " + */ this.move;
   return s;
   }   
   }
   public class Rectangle extends Shapes  {
    private String draw;
    private String erase;
    private String move;
    
    public String draw () {return draw; }
    public void draw (String d) {d = d ; }
    public String erase () {return erase; }
    public void erase (String e) { e = e ; }
    public String move () { return move; }
    public void move (String m) { m = m; } 
    
    public Rectangle ( ) {
            
        draw = " ";
        erase = " ";
        move = " ";
        System.out.println( " Default constructor" );
        
    }
    
    public Rectangle (String d, String e, String m ) {
            
        draw = " Rectangle - draw method\n";
        erase = " Rectangle - erase method\n";
        move = " Rectangle - move method\n";
        //System.out.println( draw + erase + move );
        
    }
    public String toString()
   {
   String s = "";
   s+=  this.draw;
   s+=  this.erase;
   s+=  this.move;
   return s;
   }   
   }
   public class Square extends Rectangle   {
    
    private String draw;
    private String erase;
    private String move;
   
    public String draw () {return draw; }
    public void draw (String d) {d = d ; }
    public String erase () {return erase; }
    public void erase (String e) { e = e ; }
    public String move () { return move; }
    public void move (String m) { m = m; }
    
    public Square ( ) {
            
        draw = " ";
        erase = " ";
        move = " ";
        System.out.println( " Default constructor" );
        
    }
    
    public Square (String d, String e, String m ) {
            
        draw = " Square - draw method \n";
        erase = " Square - erase method  \n";
        move = " Square - move method\n";
        
       // System.out.println( draw + erase + move );
    }
    public String toString()
   {
   String s = "";
   s+= /*" square draw " +*/ this.draw;
   s+= /*" square erase " + */ this.erase;
   s+= /*" square move " + */ this.move;
   return s;
   }   
   }
   public class Ellipse extends Shapes    {
    
    private String draw;
    private String erase;
    private String move;
    
    public String draw () {return draw; }
    public void draw (String d) {d = d ; }
    public String erase () {return erase; }
    public void erase (String e) { e = e ; }
    public String move () { return move; }
    public void move (String m) { m = m; }
    
     public Ellipse ( ) {
            
        draw = " ";
        erase = " ";
        move = " ";
        System.out.println( " Default constructor" );
     }
    
     public Ellipse (String d, String e, String m ) {
          
        draw = " ellipse - draw method \n ";
       erase = "ellipse - erase method \n";
        move = " ellipse - move method \n";
       // System.out.println( draw + erase + move);
        
    }
   public String toString()
   {
   String s = "";
   s+= /*" ellipse draw " +*/ this.draw;
   s+= /*" ellipse erase " +*/ this.erase;
   s+= /*" ellipse " + */ this.move;
   return s;
   }   
   }
   public class Circle extends Ellipse     {
    
    private String draw;
    private String erase;
    private String move;
    
    public String draw () {return draw; }
    public void draw (String d) {d = d ; }
    public String erase () {return erase; }
    public void erase (String e) { e = e ; }
    public String move () { return move; }
    public void move (String m) { m = m; }
    
    public Circle ( ) {
          
        draw = " ";
        erase = " ";
        move = " ";
        System.out.println( "Default constructor " );
    }
    
    public Circle (String d, String e, String m) {
            
        draw = "Circle - draw method \n";
        erase = "Circle - erase method \n";
        move = "Circle - move method \n";
        //System.out.println( draw + erase + move );
        
    }
    public String toString()
   {
   String s = "";
   s+= /*" circle draw " + */ this.draw;
   s+= /* " circle erase " + */ this.erase;
   s+= /* " circle move " + */ this.move;
   return s;
   }   
   }
```

Comment: It looks to me like you're supplying bad info to the ctor of your various shapes.  All the parameters are the same and essentially empty (whitespace).

Comment: Short answer - no it isn't.  Your code is riddled with mistakes, and I see no meaningful demonstration of polymorphism.

Comment: What is key to polymorphism other than have different output values to the derived classes?

Comment: Are you referring to "whitespace" as my default constructor? That will just give no value if I failed to address my method.

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't give very high marks for that submission.

For starters, you seem to not understand the benefits of inheritance. You do not actually gain anything by extending the `Shapes` class. That is the class which should act like the tester for the application. Should there be an `interface` or maybe an `abstract` base class `Shape`?

That would bring a lot of sense to what you have there because `Shape` might look like the following:

```
public abstract class Shape {
    private String draw;
    private String erase;
    private String move;
    // Put all other common stuff in here.
    // For methods that should be implemented by
    // each sub-shape mark it abstract and provide
    // the specific implementation there.
}
```

And if there was a common base class like above, why would you want to repeat all the class members in it the way you did with `Rectangle` and `Square`? That's completely unnecessary and is defeating the benefits of inheritance; the subclass inherits those from the super.

Similarly, providing an equivalent constructor for each is equally unnecessary. `public Ellipse (String d, String e, String m )` does the same thing that all the others like it do. IOW, the logic and values in the classes are largely the same and so they can be designed better; don't repeat yourself.

And again, the same applies to your class methods. They all do the same things; they set or get the values from the duplicated members. So, don't repeat them; use inheritance. All subclasses will be able to use those public methods too. And when the logic is truly different or extends the superclass then you override the method allowing the client to call the method in a polymorphic way.

Also, the requirements clearly say to call each of the three methods using polymorphism. You haven't done that yet; you've only called `toString`. In fact, you cannot accomplish it because the subclasses extend a superclass that shares no commonality to it; you gain nothing from the `Shapes` class.

So, if you want to do well on the assignment, I suggest you review the course material and give it another go.

---

Here's a short example based on some generic code.

```
public class A {

    private String first;
    private String second;

    public A() {
        first = "Hello ";
        second = "World";
    }

    public A(String first, String second) {
        this.first = first;
        this.second = second;
    }
    // getters, setters for first and secon
}

public class B extends A {

    // THERE'S NO first OR second HERE 
    // BECAUSE THEY'RE IN A!
    private String third;

    public B(String first, String second, String third) {
        super(first, second);
        this.third = third;
    }

    public void setThird(String third) {
        this.third = third;
    }

    public String getThird() {
        return third;
    }
    // THERE ARE NO GETTERS AND SETTERS HERE FOR
    // first AND second BECAUSE THEY'RE IN A!
}
```

And now, the mind-blowing use of the trivial code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String IMA = "I'm a ";
    A[] as = new A[3];
    as[0] = new A(IMA, "A");
    as[1] = new B(IMA, "B", "third string");
    as[2] = new A();
    for (A a : as) {
        System.out.println(a.getFirst() + a.getSecond());
    }
}
```

What you can't do in the above example is `a.getThird()`; you cannot depend on the `A` being a `B`.

Comment: I know how to add a method like int or double to differentiate something simple like height for each subclass and call each value. I don't have any string reference in my book to polymorph string. I could use super for 1 or 2 of the child class methods and change one of the String outputs for each shape but I think that is off-target.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your comment. Yes, you can differentiate between types of shapes. A circle FE would have a radius. But all things common to all shapes should not be repeated. Yes, you should override the methods in the subs if they're different or extend the base but if they're the same you shouldn't. In its current form it's difficult in even seeing the use of sub-classes. I think I could simplify that down to a single shape class that has a `String type` or `Type type` where `Type` is an `enum`. @sjames14

Comment: This is fundamental programming 2 and I don't think much is expected like to invoke a radius measure. That would probably look good if I had the programming knowledge, especially to apply calculus to my programs. I think my situation is a bit lenient given the information I have been taught. I am more looking at how I can use polymorphism in a string for all of my classes.

Comment: I think you're missing the point. I'm not suggesting what you think; I'm simply stating shapes are different in different ways but they are the same too. I'm trying to get you to understand that you *are* likely worried about using polymorphism but you're not doing it correctly. See me recent edit.

Comment: @sjames14, I would recommend that you debug your code and notice that an instance of a `Square` would have duplicated fields. It would have its own `move`, `erase`, and `draw` `String`s and a `Rectangle.move`, `Rectangle.erase`, `Rectangle.draw` `String`s. They're not the same.

Comment: If I were to apply radius to my circle and ellipse that would be extending the requirements. How could I separate those two simply? I just need to understand what the code would look like if I had a string to separate the different shapes. Like triangle " is 1/2 of base times width" and square is "base times height" sort of thing. Could I call a string method to differentiate from one another?

Comment: I can't tell you the exact answer; it's important that I don't do your homework and your comments don't match the code. But if you're asking how you would differentiate between types to, say, get their areas. *That's the point; **you wouldn't differentiate them***; You would simply call `shape.getArea();` because all shapes have an area. That's the beauty of what you're learning. What you'd do is `@Override` the `getArea()` method in each shape so you can define the specific way to get the area of *that* shape. @sjames14

Comment: So you are suggesting I make an int or double to define the difference between the shapes?

Comment: @sjames14, I am not suggesting that. I'm saying that every 2D shape has a height and width. So, there's no reason to differentiate a specific shape. All you care about, in this example, is that you need to get the area of *any* shape no matter if it's a square, circle, parallelogram, etc. So, given a `shape[]` I *have* to be able to say `shape[i].getArea()` and not even worry about it; I know I've got shapes and shapes got areas.

Comment: I feel like I am doing integrals. I need to just simply separate my shapes with an arbitrary code that uses polymorphism.

Comment: I added a bit of code. I can't promise you it won't confuse you more but I'm going to have to cut off  the help. @sjames14, please see the most recent edit.